# Jquery Mobile error message when no internet connection to load google maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, google-maps, jquery-mobile

What I am trying to achieve from past 2 days is that - I could show a error msg on my jquery mobile page when there is no internet connection that 'Sorry, No internet connection.'

I have tried alot of stuff but none worked. Code below is now when last I tried by using try-catch block. But even this ain't helping. Following happens when i load the page in browser -

1. When Internet Connection Available - Map Loaded and works perfectly fine.
2. When No Internet Connection - I get blank page. without page header and footer. with some default grey background and that looks bad for my application. :(

Any kind of help is appreciable. I am still learning.

Code am using right now is given below -

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<script src="SpryAssets/SpryTabbedPanels.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="SpryAssets/SpryTabbedPanels.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/master.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/jquery.mobile.structure-1.0.min.css"              type="text/css" media="screen" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/jquery.mobile.theme-1.0.min.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
  <script src="assets/js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
  <style type="text/css"> 
     #map_canvas { height: 330px; width: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px }
  </style>

</head> 
<body>

  <div data-role="header" data-theme="e">
  <a data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext" rel="external" href="index.html#page2"></a>
    <h1>Maps</h1>   
  </div>
  <div data-role="content" data-theme="d">  
    <div id="map_canvas">
      <script type="text/javascript">
         function initialize(){
           try{
                var locations = [
               ['Dr. Martin Luther King Library',37.3356,-121.8853, 4],
               ['Duncan Hall',37.3325,-121.8820, 5],
                   ['Clark Hall',37.3360,-121.8827, 3],
                   ['Event Center',37.3355,-121.8797, 2],
                   ['Student Union',37.3369,-121.8806,  1]
                 ];

                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
                          zoom: 16,
                          center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.3369,-121.8806),
                          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                       });

                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                var marker, i;

               for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) 
                 {  
                    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
                         map: map
                    });

                  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                    return function() {
                            infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
                            infowindow.open(map, marker);
                          } 
             })(marker, i));
                 }
                   }
             catch(err)
               {
                 document.getElementById("map_canvas").text='Sorry, No internet connection.';
               }
         }

       google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

  </script>  
  </div>
</div>
<div data-role="footer" data-theme="e">
<h4>&copy; blah-blah Inc.</h4>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How can your site be available,if there is no internet connection?

Comment: na, actually i am making a jquery mobile app. So there are static features to it which will work fine when no internet connection is available.
Only for the map functionality it requires internet connection. :/

Comment: But I think so by using this the page map.html as in this page wont load and give me an error msg. 
Instead can you suggest me some way, I can show the error msg in the between the <div data-role="content"> ... </div> 
This is because by doing this .. my page header and footer would be displayed and along with it at the place where maps was to be show - an error msg will be show.

Comment: Check my updated answer. *It is not tested, so there could be typos.*

Comment: Sir, Thanks for all your responses. But after making the changes with respect to this
     <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" onload="javascript:initialize()"       onerror="javascript:$('#map_canvas').html('No internet connection')">
     </script> 
only the page header and footer are getting rendered in either case when I load page with internet connection ON or OFF.

I am not sure but I think so the script onload and onerror events are not working as expected.

Comment: What it 'prints' in 'OFF' case ?

Comment: same thing in both the case ON and OFF - blank content div with header and footer.

Comment: Try to put `<script src="http://.....google..."></script>` inside of `<body>`, like I have updated my answer.

Comment: Na, no changes still the same result.

Comment: Do you get any errors in your console?

Comment: No Error Sir just the blank content div with header and footer.

Answer (score 1):

`script` element triggers `onerror` event, when it can't load the script. You can add handler and track whether script loaded successfully:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" 
        onerror="javascript:alert('No internet connection.')"></script>
```

**UPDATE:** You could try something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<script src="SpryAssets/SpryTabbedPanels.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="SpryAssets/SpryTabbedPanels.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/master.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/jquery.mobile.structure-1.0.min.css"              type="text/css" media="screen" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/jquery.mobile.theme-1.0.min.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
  <script src="assets/js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>    
  <script type="text/javascript">
      function initialize(){
         //..... Your code with removed try/catch block
      }
  </script>  
  <style type="text/css"> 
     #map_canvas { height: 330px; width: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px }
  </style>

</head> 
<body>

  <div data-role="header" data-theme="e">
  <a data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext" rel="external" href="index.html#page2"></a>
    <h1>Maps</h1>   
  </div>
  <div data-role="content" data-theme="d">  
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
</div>
<div data-role="footer" data-theme="e">
<h4>&copy; blah-blah Inc.</h4>
</div>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" onload="javascript:initialize()" onerror="javascript:$('#map_canvas').html('No internet connection')"></script>
</body>
</html>
```